# Change Container widget background color on press

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

I am trying to change the background color of my container widget inside the Expanded when a button is pressed in BottomNavigationBar.

I am using a list of color and a variable index to traverse the list front and back.

Even though I used setState(() {}), the color is not changing.

h(double x) and w(double x) are the methods that return the height or width of the screen times x using a media query.

Here is my code: the list:

```
List<Color> col = [Colors.grey, Colors.red, Colors.pink];
int index = 0;
```

BottomNavigationBar:

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.orange,
            height: h(0.07),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (index == 0) {
                    } else {
                      setState(() {
                        index--;
                      });
                    }
                  },
                ),
                Icon(
                  Icons.color_lens_rounded,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (index == col.length - 1) {
                    } else {
                      setState(() {
                        index++;
                      });
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Widget whose color has to be changed

```
Expanded(
   child: Container(
    color: col[index],
     child: Column(
        children: [],
      ),
   ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

run this code, then hope so you can modify as you want

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  static const TextStyle optionStyle =
      TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
  static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Text(
      'Index 0: Home',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 1: Business',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 2: School',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('BottomNavigationBar Sample'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.business),
            label: 'Business',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.school),
            label: 'School',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```